# Removing similar characters from field

Tags: r

I have File1.csv contains 3000 records, from which I need to remove characters not related to address.

Each record starts from "&" or "A/O".
I need to clean my "Address1" field, if it's no address related info in the field,
I need to have empty record.

Example:

```
File1.csv:

Address1
&&2340 Clemb Street
&&564 7th Street
&&&10th Street
A/O11th Street
A/ONorth Street
A/O/OSouth Street
A/Ocareof
A/Otttt
A/Oyuyuyu
A/Ouiuiuiuiui
A/O/yuyyuyuyuyugggh 4510th Street
&uhhhhhello 56 11th Street
```

I am expecting result in File1 -without A/O, A/O/O, A/Ouiuiuiui  etc.:

File1.csv:

```
Address1
2340 Clemb Street
564 7th Street
10th Street
11th Street
North Street
South Street
<blank record>
<blank record>
<blank record>
<blank record>
4510th Street
56 11th Street
```

Thanx for help!

Comment: I'm curious, why is your data looking like that in the first place?

Comment: Pls import the dataset from CSV and use smth like `dput(head(my.dataset))` so we can work with it.

Answer (score 1):

There are almost certainly fancier matching patterns you could use, but `gsub()` and the following seem to get the job done with this dataset:

```
x <- c('&&2340 Clemb Street',
       '&&564 7th Street',
       '&&&10th Street',
       'A/O11th Street',
       'A/ONorth Street',
       'A/O/OSouth Street')

gsub("&|A/O|/O", "", x)
#-----
[1] "2340 Clemb Street" "564 7th Street"    "10th Street"       "11th Street"      
[5] "North Street"      "South Street"
```

Intro to regex can be found [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html).

Comment: To Chase: Thank you, but I meant little bit more complicated -  I added more info to my post. It's 3000 records, each starts from "&" or "A/O" or "A/O/O". But it's more unrelated info after - something like:

Comment: A/O/Ojkjkjkjkyyy156 3rd Street      A/Otytytyty2nd Street and it's 3000 different records

Comment: @heli_77 - this isn't really an R question, but more a regex question. The link above is a great introduction to regex, so you really just need to sit down and think through something clever enough to remove the offending character sets. Or do it in a few steps.

Comment: Try these two: `"^A(/O)+/?[a-z]* ?"` and `"^&+[a-z]* ?"`.

Comment: Thank you for regex link. Looks like this problem not for R - there is no way to assign and erase similar characters in the string...?  Something like: "Is like AAA*" in MsAccess or "Like AAA%" in T-SQL..